# Granting access for admin's to view customsettings object?

Tags: managed-package, customsetting, configuration

We have created a managed package  and a custom link for inserting data's into the customsetting object and since the object is in "protected" format,its not even visible to the admin who installs it.How can we make it accessible only to the admin but not to the user in protected format?Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the custom setting is protected you wont be able to directly enter values into that setting unless the package provider has created an interface to do so such as a custom VisualForce page and controller to create the settings.

If the provider has created the package and it has Aloha status they should be able to log in using Subscriber access to modify the values in this custom setting.

In your situation i would reach out to the provider of the package and see if they can assist further, they may be able to create a VF page / Controller which could then be set so that only a System Admin profile has access to the VF page and provide the functionality you're requesting or to log in via subscriber access and populate the settings as you require them.